# download file from DropBox with AXIOS and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, axios, dropbox

i`m trying to download a File from DropBox Api with axios on nodejs backend server. But i get error when I'm calling this function.
I have already tested the get statement with postman and it works fine. ( without nodejs)

```
getDropBoxDataFile: async (res) => {

        
        try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download',
      {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            'Bearer [secret token]',
          'Dropbox-API-Arg': `{"path": "/Apps/adrezze/mails/150.pdf"}`,
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
          Host: 'content.dropboxapi.com',
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(res)
} catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
```

error:

````
(node:22652) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (...backEndServer\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (...backEndServer\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (...backEndServer\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
```
... lots of config data at the end of this error
````

Comment: Is that 400 error referring to the call to the Dropbox API? If so, what does the response body contain? It should be a more useful error.

Comment: Are you using VSCode? Is it possible one of your extensions is sneakily setting ``NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0``?
Stumbled upon this, maybe it's related... https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync/issues/776

Comment: With ```set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=1``` in the cmd i could remove the warning.

Comment: But the Error still exists :(

Comment: at the end of the Error: ```},
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}```

Answer (score 0):

This Endpoint is listening to POST-Method instead of GET.
[Dropbox API Documentation][1]

```
var axios = require('axios');

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download',
  headers: { 
    'Dropbox-API-Arg': '{"path":"/Apps/adrezze/mails/150.pdf"}',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer BEARER_TOKEN_HERE'
  }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Depending on the type of Dropbox Account Business/Private you have to provide  'Dropbox-API-Path-Root' and 'Dropbox-API-Select-User' header or not.
[1]: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download